# Instagram Client Side Authentication Issue

Tags: python, oauth, instagram

I'm have an issue getting an access token. I keep getting OAuth Exception.

If I type this [URL](https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/oauth/authorize/?client_id=2fba7fcb2f3e40dba7637c383cb86ad6&redirect_uri=http://www.johnymoswag.com&response_type=token) in the Chrome/Safari browser on Mac:

I get redirected to this [URL](https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=2fba7fcb2f3e40dba7637c383cb86ad6).

With this error:

> {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "You
>   must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri
>   parameters"}

The auth flow previously working before in my app. I stopped dev on it for a while and came back to the project to give it an update. Only changes I've made were my `redirect_uri` and `client_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you need to percent encode your `redirect_uri`:
So it'll be this:

> http%3A%2F%2Fwww.johnymoswag.com

with the `%2F` being the `"/"` and the `%3A` is ":"

Everything between your ".com" and "`/oath`" was invalid. Maybe Instagram changed the URL
at some point for authorization. This should work though.

> https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENTID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.johnymoswag.com&response_type=token

just change CLIENTID to the client id that you want to have access to.